# How do you disable the window preview in Ubuntu dock (GNOME sidebar)?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

If you have multiple windows of the same application open and click on the application icon in the dock or the sidebar, then a small preview window is shown.

[image: screenshot of window preview]

That is annoying and I would rather like to switch to the application immediately. I think that was possible in previous Ubuntu GNOME versions.

How can I disable this small preview window in the dock?

Comment: @pomsky you replaced "sidebar" with "dock" in the question, so users that don't know that this is called "dock" (like me) won't be able to find this question with the answer. Maybe it is enough to mention GNOME sidebar here? :-)

Comment: Good idea! Edited and put sidebar in parentheses (brackets) too. :-)

Comment: Also if you remember correctly this dock is not exactly the same thing from older Ubuntu GNOME releases (unless you also have been using the "Dash to Dock" extension). The "GNOME sidebar" (called dash) used to appear *only* in "Activities" overview, not always on your desktop. This dock is an extension shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 (a fork of Dash to Dock extension actually).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On your Terminal run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'skip'
```

Or you can try(This will allow you to cycle through the open windows by clicking on the icon):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

To revert the action:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The 'cycle-windows' option is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A perhaps more novice-friendly approach, that also allows you to see the other options that exist for this setting, would be using the [Dash-to-Dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/) extension, which is actually what Ubuntu uses for its dock, albeit with less configuration options.

First, you need to be able to install GNOME Shell extensions, so make sure that you have `chrome-gnome-shell` and `gnome-tweaks` installed by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell gnome-tweaks
```

Also, install the GNOME Shell integration extension [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en) or [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/), depending on the browser of your choice.

Then, install Dash-to-Dock from the [GNOME Shell extension website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) by turning the switch to *ON* and clicking *Install*.

After this, open Tweaks and go to *Extensions* → *Dash to Dock* → *click the gear icon* → *Behavior* and select the *Click action* option that you wish.

[image]